# Scala3 doesn't display type mismatch or format errors in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, syntax-error, scala-3

I'm using Scala 3.3.1 and Intellij isn't giving me helpful build error outputs and no error highlighting.

For example, if my project uses any 3.x Scala SDK, and I have the following incorrect code, it does not display anything on the IDE itself to tell me there is a type error:
[image: Scala3 code]

And when compiling, the console output is always the same thing no matter what error it is.

```
scalac: Error: 'java.lang.String dotty.tools.dotc.reporting.Message.msg()'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String dotty.tools.dotc.reporting.Message.msg()'
    at dotty.tools.xsbt.DelegatingReporter.doReport(DelegatingReporter.java:47)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.reporting.Reporter.issueUnconfigured(Reporter.scala:158)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.reporting.Reporter.go$1(Reporter.scala:181)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.reporting.Reporter.issueIfNotSuppressed(Reporter.scala:200)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.reporting.Reporter.report(Reporter.scala:203)
    (etc...)
```

My project involves a lot of complicated types and methods and when every time there is a type mismatch, a misspelt variable or literally anything tiny out of place, IntelliJ tells me nothing at all about what the error might be or where it is, making my work almost impossible.

Oppositely, if I then reassign my project's SDK to Scala 2.x instead, what I want happening happens:
[image: Scala3 code]

And equally, it returns helpful error messages:

```
(...)Main.scala:3:21
type mismatch;
 found   : String("test")
 required: Int
    val test: Int = "test"
```

Sadly my work wont let me use Scala 2 but it's becoming impossible without getting error messages and error highlighting like in Scala 2 on the same IDE. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using SBT? If so, can you show your build.sbt and plugins.sbt files? The error message you get seems weird to me.

Comment: @GaëlJ I'm not sure I'm afraid, how can I locate this information?

Comment: Sounds like you're only using IntelliJ but no build tool then. How do you switch from Scala 2 to Scala 3?

Comment: Is your IntelliJ up to date? There was a lot of fixes in latest versions.